# Activate COM object using website doesn't work in Windows 2003 server

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, permissions, dcom

I have been trying really hard to activate and launch a COM object using an ASP.NET web application. The aspx website has a code-behind file that has a reference to this COM object (which is an actual application - a CAD software). When required, the VB code creates (or launches) the application.

The complete set-up works in a Win-XP (32-bit) environment both under debugging using visual studio and when the website is accessed by an outside user (through IIS server in XP). But the same application doesn't get activated when it is hosted onto the Win-2003 (32-bit) IIS server. I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

The way I have setup in Win-XP was to grant ASP user and Internet guest user permissions to the COM object in the DCOM Config and since the windows firewall is enabled, I add the exe file (associated with the COM object) to the exception list. For the case of Win-2003 server, I add the Network Service permission to the COM object. But the setup doesn't seem to work at all.

I am not sure what I am missing and how to get the application to launch. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A Couple of things to check:

- Make sure your'e using the ASPNET user, not the old classic ASP user
- Also Apply the ASPNET user and NewtworkService User to the Launch and Activation Permisions in the DCOM Config if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Hi Jon,

I gave the ASPNET and NetworkService users the lauch and activation permissions but it didn't work (also restarted the computer after giving permissions). I still get the same "Object reference not set to instance of an object" error.

I believe ASPNET user is used for IIS 5, and for IIS 6 you need to use NetworkService. I am using Windows server 2003 which has IIS 6.0 installed.

Any other ideas? Like giving permissions in the Inetpub folder or to the actual .exe file in the program files?

Comment: Unfortunatly that is the exent of my megre knowledge and experience in this area. Hopefully some one wiser than me can help you here.

Sorry!!